# Why I have this error when I try to dispose a resource in the finally statment of a try block?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some problem disposing a resource.

I heve this code:

```
    class ChartHelper
    {

        //public static System.Drawing.Image GetPdfChart(int percentage)
        public static System.Drawing.Bitmap GetPdfChart(int percentage)
        {
            if (percentage == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int WIDTH = 130;
            int HEIGHT = 10;


            //using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
            //{
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), Color.LightGreen, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
                    {
                        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));

                        using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(WIDTH * percentage / 100, HEIGHT))
                        {
                            Rectangle cropped = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                            {
                                g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropped.Width, cropped.Height), cropped, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                                //g.Save();
                                //String filename = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".png";
                                //target.Save(filename);
                                //return filename;

                                return bitmap;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
               bitmap.Dispose(); 
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see at the beginning I create a **BitMap** object, in this way:

```
bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

into a **try** block.

At the end of the block I have the **finaly** in wich I try to dispose the resource:

```
finally
{
    bitmap.Dispose(); 
}
```

But here it give me the following error message:

> **Error   2   Use of unassigned local variable 'bitmap'**

Why? What can I do to solve it? (I don't want to use the **using** statment)

Tnx

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use a `using` statement? That's what it's designed for.

Comment: You should not be disposing `bitmap` at all! You are returning it to the caller, it is the caller's responsibility to dispose it.

Answer (score 8):

> Why?

Because `bitmap` isn't definitely assigned, according to the rules of the language specification. Imagine if the `Bitmap` constructor threw an exception. What would you dispose?

> What can I do to solve it? (I don't want to use the using statment)

Well you *can* use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try
{
    bitmap = ...;
    // Code using bitmap
}
finally
{
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

However, I would *strongly* advise you to use a `using` statement for this. It's what it's designed for, and it's the idiomatic approach.

As a slightly separate matter, you're *returning* the bitmap from the middle of the block - but you're disposing it. Do you really want to return a reference to a disposed bitmap? What do you expect the caller to be able to do with it? You might want to consider *only* disposing the bitmap on failure. e.g.

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
bool success = false;
try
{
    bitmap = ...;
    // Code using bitmap
    ...
    success = true;
    return bitmap;
}
finally
{
    if (bitmap != null && !success)
    {
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

At this point of course you *do* have a good reason not to use a `using` statement...

Comment: Except that the OP is *returning* the bitmap from the function, and so shouldn't be disposing of it at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, I'd just noticed that and added something to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't assign anything to bitmap, you cant dispose it!
even assigning "null" will solve this. 
Although its not as "clean" as you would want it.
Assigning null on declaration, then checking if it's not null before disposing it, will be better.
Watch it! if you want to return the object.

Answer (score 0):

As of the `bitmap.Dispose` call, `bitmap` may not have a value (if `new Bitmap` throws an exception).

Since in the normal case you're *returning* the bitmap to the caller, I'd probably do this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
```

...so that `bitmap` definitely has a value, then add a `null` check to your `finally` clause:

```
finally
{
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

...and shuffle around when returning:

```
Bitmap rv = bitmap;
bitmap = null;
return rv;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Dispose at all on the bitmap, since it is returned by the function:

```
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap GetPdfChart(int percentage)
    {
        if (percentage == 0) return null;

        int WIDTH = 130;
        int HEIGHT = 10;

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), Color.LightGreen, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));

                using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(WIDTH * percentage / 100, HEIGHT))
                {
                    Rectangle cropped = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                    using (Graphics graphicsTarget = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                    {
                        graphicsTarget .DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropped.Width, cropped.Height), cropped, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                        return bitmap; // IT IS RETURNED HERE, SO DO NOT DISPOSE
                        // should'nt this be target anyway?
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Use the function like this to make sure the Dispose happens properly:

```
using(var bmp = GetPdfChart(somePercentage))
{
     // code goes here.
}
```

however if you really need to make sure, in case of error, the bitmap is Disposed properly

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap GetPdfChart(int percentage)
{
    if (percentage == 0) return null;

    int WIDTH = 130;
    int HEIGHT = 10;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    bool functionReturned = false;
    try
    {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), Color.LightGreen, Color.Red, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));

                using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(WIDTH * percentage / 100, HEIGHT))
                {
                    Rectangle cropped = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

                    using (Graphics graphicsTarget = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                    {
                        graphicsTarget .DrawImage(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropped.Width, cropped.Height), cropped, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        functionReturned = true;

                        return bitmap; // IT IS RETURNED HERE, SO DO NOT DISPOSE
                        // should'nt this be target anyway?
                    }                   
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    finally
    {
        if(!functionReturned && bitmap != null) bitmap.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably wants to dispose in error handling if something *other* than `new Bitmap` goes wrong. The above won't call `Dispose` if an exception occurs later.